# Jquery document.ready is not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery

The document.ready function is not responding while my page load.
And also i am facing problem with .submit function. Please help.
Please help me to rewrite this code.
**I just want to design a form in php to check whether the given email id is already present in the database or not using jquery ajax
Please help .... ! I am getting late in my school project.**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                alert("Working..");
                $("#userSubmit").submit(function(){
                    alert("Working ..");
                    var email=document.getElementById("userEamil").value;
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        data:"SELECT * FROM user WHERE userEmail='"+email+"'",
                        url:'common1.php',
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            $result=$.parseJSON($data);
                            alert($result);
                            return false;
                        },
                        error:function(data)
                        {
                            alert(data);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: " $("#userSubmit").submit(function{" missing parameter after function
example: function()

Comment: And what about $(document).ready(function() { });

Comment: Thanks but still there are problems in this code ..

Comment: please provide the more details (html code)

Comment: Please look at your raw HTML and verify the jquery is actually loaded before this script is loaded. Also, I hope this code never runs on a production site because your exposing your database to a sql injection attack that even my 4 year old could figure out how to leverage.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does your first `alert("Working..")` run at all? Does the `alert("Working ..")` in the submit handler run when submitting? For what reason do you `return false` in the success and error handlers, what do you think that will accomplish?

Comment: Please help me rewrite this code.... My main motive is to check the given email is already present in the database or not

Answer (score 1):

You have some error in your code, i hope following code will do the work. and for further problem please check the `$.ajax` portion.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        // alert("Working..");
        $("#userSubmit").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Working ..");
            var email = document.getElementById("#userEamil").value;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userEmail='" + email + "'",
                url: 'common1.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $result = $.parseJSON($data);
                    alert($result);
                    return false;
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="userSubmit" action="">
            <input type="email">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <input type="email" >
    <input id="userSubmit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/1uor0gxf/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userSubmit").click(function(){
        var email = $("userEamil").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:`SELECT * FROM user WHERE userEmail='${email}'`,
            url:'common1.php',
            success:function(data)
            {
                $result=$.parseJSON($data);
                alert($result);
                return false;
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="userEamil" />
  <input type="button" id="userSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      //alert("Working..");
      $("#userSubmit").submit(function() {
           //alert("Working ..");
                  var email = $(this).closest("form").find("input[name='emailbox']").val();
                  console.log(email);
                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userEmail='" + email + "'",
                    url: 'common1.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                      $result = $.parseJSON($data);
                      alert($result);
                      return false;
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                      alert(data);
                      return false;
                    }
                  });
                });
              });
            </script>

<html>
    <body>
        <form id="userSubmit">
            <input type="email" id="userEmail" name="emailbox">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. Instead, explain what your code does and how/why it may solve the question.